# Retrieve value from mysql database json_encode the value in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to retrieve value from mysql database and covert it into json.

```
  <?php
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","name","password");
   if (!$con)
   {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT Inc_number FROM Increment WHERE id=1"); 
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
  echo $row['Inc_number'];
   echo "<br />";
   }
   mysql_close($con);
   $objJSON['sample'] = $result;
   $objJSON = json_encode($objJSON);
   echo($objJSON);
  ?>
```

I get the output like this,

4

{"sample":null}

I want 4 instead of null. What am i doing wrong here?
Help me please

Thanks,

Comment: $result is a mysql result handle. It has no meaning whatsoever outside of this particular script invocation - json-encoding it and sending it to the browser is pointless. $row, however, will be an array representing a single row of data from that $result, and that array **CAN** be json-encoded and sent over and still have meaning.

Comment: i tried that also...but didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is `$row['Inc_number']`, not `$result`.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Inc_number FROM Increment WHERE id=1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo json_encode(array('sample' => $row['Inc_number']));
```